# Selenium Python respond to multiple actions in same tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a small browser automation tool using key macros basically to open different urls and click a couple buttons. The idea is to have something like a raspberry pi that can be plugged into a tv and used to stream media from those different routes (urls), accessible as quickly as possible. The goal is to have a small stream deck with the different feeds, and each button press will quickly switch between and them. The script must go to the url and click a button to maximize the video. I have it down for a single instance, but I want Selenium to continue using one tab after it has opened already. I tried running chrome with the remote debugging flag, but it doesn't seem to work consistently and still opens a second blank window (with data; in the nav bar), then sometimes fails and stops with error: not connected to DevTools.. Is there a way to have selenium use only one window/browser in separate calls?

I tried opening chrome with remote debugging flag first:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-profile
```

And have this option in my selenium driver:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
```

I saw that in some other posts..